# netcdf doesn't work in Node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, netcdf

I'm trying to encode a NetCDF file in Node.js program, by using the netcdf(https://www.npmjs.com/package/netcdf) library.

Now, once I run a program, I get an error below.

```
C:\app [master +2 ~1 -0 !]> npm start

> spaceapps@1.0.0 start C:\app
> node server.js

C:\app\node_modules\text-encoding\lib\encoding.js:979
      throw TypeError('Called as a function. Did you forget \'new\'?');
      ^

TypeError: Called as a function. Did you forget 'new'?
    at TypeError (native)
    at Object.TextDecoder (C:\app\node_modules\text-encoding\lib\encoding.js:979:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app\node_modules\netcdf\util\readbinary.js:4:40)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\app\node_modules\netcdf\util\type.js:4:14)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\v\\nodev5.9.1\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Nodist\\bin\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! spaceapps@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the spaceapps@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the spaceapps package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs spaceapps
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls spaceapps
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\app\npm-debug.log
C:\app [master +3 ~1 -0 !]>
```

It seems there is an error in a library.
I appreciate if someone tells me a solution for it.

Comment: You should create an issue on the repository instead https://github.com/metocean/netcdfjs/issues

Answer (score 0):

As the developer said, He has [no plans in the short or medium term to continue development](https://github.com/metocean/netcdfjs/issues/1), so you could consider use [netcdfjs](https://github.com/cheminfo-js/netcdfjs), that it's a javascript library that allows to read NetCDF v3 files. Because it's a NodeJS package you can run it server side, and for regular size files you can read it online, here you have an [example](http://www.cheminfo.org/Spectra/Utilities/NetCDF_explorer/index.html).